# Merge [f#-make] into [f#-fake]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

[f#-make](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/f%23-make) is already [f#-fake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/f%23-fake):

> F# Make (FAKE) is an open-source build automation system

While [f#-fake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/f%23-fake) is [f#-fake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/f%23-fake):

> F#-Fake is an open-source build automation system built using F#, similar to make and rake.

So why continue keeping 2 separate tags?

Comment: [f#-make] has 10 questions, just retag them and this is done.

Comment: @Joe: I'd like a synonym to be added to avoid this situation in the future again